# using qmgr to list all the nodes with a given attribute

Tags: grid, cluster-computing, pbs, torque

We are using a torque PBS and we had to update many node's parameters using qmgr.
Did it by hand invoking something like 'set node n44 properties-=unneeded_param' for each node in question.

Now, how do I list all nodes which have a given property specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the nodes with the specific property, run:

`pbsnodes :unneeded_property`

Easy, quick & dirty method to remove all those properties:

```
# sed -i 's/unneeded_property//g' /var/spool/torque/server_priv/nodes
```

...and then restart pbs_server (and the scheduler, if applicable).

The "proper" method, as you indicated, is to do:

`# qmgr -c 'set node node01 properties-=unneeded_property'`

However, AFAIK there's no way to do mass changes within `qmgr` (e.g., with a wildcard), but you can do it in a simple bash loop one-liner.